# model predicts NaN

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to learn and practice on Tensorflow.js. 
So, I tried to train a neural network on a [,2] shaped array as x (as I understood, this would simulate a problem where I have x samples that each one has 2 variables) and a [,1] array as y (what would mean if I'm correct, that the combination of my 2 variables generate 1 output).

And I tried to code it:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, inputShape: [2] }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 64, inputShape: [2] }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [64] }));
        // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
        model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' });

        // Generate some synthetic data for training.
        const xs = tf.tensor([[1,5], [2,10], [3,15], [4,20], [5,25], [6,30], [7,35], [8,40]], [8, 2]);
        const ys = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [8, 1]);

        // Train the model using the data.
        model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 100 }).then(() => {
            // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
            // Open the browser devtools to see the output
            model.predict(tf.tensor([10, 50], [1, 2])).print();
        });
```

But, what I am facing is that when I try to predict the [10,50] input, I have the following console output:

> Tensor
>   [[NaN],]

So, I think my problem might be very simple, but I am really stuck with this and probably it is a matter of some background knowledge I'm missing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first layer takes the shape of the input data

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, inputShape: [2] }))
```

The inputShape is [2], which means that your input x is of shape [2].
The last layer `unit` value gives the dimension of the output y.

```
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [64] }));
```

So the shape of y should be [1]

In this case, the `NaN` prediction is related to the number of epochs for your training. If you decrease it to 2 or 3, it will return a numerical value. Actually, the error is related to how your optimizer is updating the weights. Alternatively, you can change the optimizer to `adam` and it will be fine.

Comment: Hello there I am facing same error tried what you said but it is no use it doesn't return any numerical value at all

Answer (score 0):

I think I am late but I hope this helps someone.
I got same problem once and it was because I am getting training and testing data from file using "fs" dependency and I solved the problem by just doing this to the returned variable before returning it to the main function to start training:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`

I don't know the reason but for some reason the tensorflow model only accepts JSON Array and not any JavaScript array so just by doing this you are converting your array to json array instead of leaving it as JavaScript Array.

Hope this saves someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this same issue for the past 2 days, and the problem was that I trained my model with a GPU (using Google Colab) and performed inference on the CPU. After changing the settings on Google Colab to use no hardware acceleration, my problem was fixed!

Hope this helps someone in the future.